# Add arraylist into while loop from different class

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist

I have an array list in another class called Ratings.

I then have a while loop that i want to use to display the data along with the time in a graph.  Most of it is working except for the main data part coming from the array list.

My code is below:

```
    XYSeries series = new XYSeries("XYSeries");
    int i = 0;
    int time = 0;
    double e = 0;
    ArrayList<Double> emotionvalues = Rating.Array;
    while (i < emotionvalues.size()) {
        series.add(time, emotions[e]);
        e++;
        time++;
        i++;
    }
    dataset.addSeries(series);
    return dataset;
}
```

At the moment I am getting an error saying "The type of the expression must be an array type but it resolved to ArrayList"

Comment: What don't you understand about the error message? Where can you use the `[e]` syntax? What is an `ArrayList`? These are the questions you should be asking before posting a question.

Comment: If you just Google the compiler error all the hits answer your question.

Comment: nm thanks guys, been doing this for hours.  tired now.

Answer (score 0):

Two errors maybe? The `List.get` instead of `[]` and it is better style to use `int i` as index instead of `double e`.

```
    series.add(time, emotions[e]);

    series.add(time, emotionValues.get(i));
```

Also the loop can be written as:

```
for (int i = 0; i < emotionValues.size(); ++i) {
    series.add(time, emotionValues.get(i));
```

without the later `i++`.